# Какой Linux дистрибутив лучше выбрать для "smart" техники?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, дистрибутив

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, какой лучше дистрибутив выбрать для портативной техники, в которой всё работает в фоне без GUI, с чистой заточкой под требуемые операции, без всякого ненужного барохла, которое будет грузить систему при загрузке и в процессе работы.

Кто уже запутался, **на каких linux'ах работает Smart бытовуха** : холодильники, роботы-пылесосы, роутеры, кофеварки, чайники и т.д.?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- По любому кто-то должен спросить, "а что у вас будет работать и на каком мини-компьютере", отвечаю :

> Будет работать java программа, которая будет использовать wifi модуль,
>   соответственно будет активно работать с интернетом (tcp server/client) и локальной сетью
>   (ну локальная сеть нужна, только для web интерфейса, чтобы удалённо
>   можно запускать и выключать), желательно ещё хотелось чтобы можно
>   сделать вывод звука. И самое главное, мини-компьютером будет служить Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем вас не устраевает Kali :D

Comment: @pavel1787mego для того чтобы "с чайника" взламывать сервера? )))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На разных бытовых приборах работает своя ОС. Даже не так: на приборах редко работают ОС. Обычно, простые контроллеры. Какой на каждом устройстве — нужно смотреть отдельно. Там же Вам напишут как взаимодействовать с сетью (если можно) через этот контроллер.

На Raspberry Pi лучше всего ставить Raspbian, так как эта система "родная", соответственно Вы получите минимум проблем совместимости. Linux система сама по себе умеет очень много (работа с сетью, любой Web интерфейс и и.д.), да и имеет полную JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Огромный выбор здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/66194/

Из них можно выделить:
Raspbian Server Edition - облегченный стандартный дистрибутив
Raspbian Minimal - полностью минимализированный дистрибутив

Еще есть Prota OS, но это уже по сути готовое решение для умных устройств.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите установку Ubuntu Core [ссылка на офф.сайт](https://www.ubuntu.com/core).
Очень много документации, заточен под IoT